# Unit Testing Private Functions within jQuery Plugins

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jquery-plugins, qunit

I really want to start unit testing my code,  so I thought to start adding tests to some plugins I've written using QUnit.  However, I like to create custom classes/objects within my plugins to group properties and methods together, and have some separation.  On top of that, these have their own private methods.

I'm trying to get my head around the best way to refactor my code to allow for unit testing.  I don't like the idea of making everything public, or polluting the window object with a bunch of custom objects.  But maybe that's how things should be done?

Perhaps I just need some better ideas as to workflow.  Like maybe the scripts for development are all public, but when I minify it using Grunt it wraps it back up into an anonymous function?

Anyway, I wrote this quickly as a crude example of what I'm talking about as far as my plugin structure.  How would I write a unit test to test the 'getNewPosition' method?

```
(function( $ ) {
"use strict";

// Custom Object
var MyClass = function( element ) {
    var speed = 1;
    // Private Function
    var getNewPosition = function() {
        var currentPosition = parseFloat( element.css( "top" ) );
        return currentPosition + speed;
    }

    return {
        // Public Function
        update: function() {
            var newPosition = getNewPosition();
            element.css( "top", newPosition.toString() + "px" );
        }
    }
};


// jQuery Plugin
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    var aryElements = [];
    this.each( function() {
        var myObj = new MyClass( $( this ) );
        aryElements.push ( myObj );

    });

    $( window ).on( "scroll", function( event ) {
        $.each( aryElements, function( i, element ) {
            element.update();
        });

    });
    return this;
};
}( jQuery ));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to test private methods in JS. I suggest writing tests for anything public and ensuring that you test all code branches so that you are positive that your private functions are called. In your code example, the `MyClass` constructor is globally available, and the `update` method calls `getNewPosition()` so the answer there would be to ensure you test `update` thoroughly, which will in turn run `getNewPosition` (and thus be tested to a degree).

I'd write something like this in QUnit:

```
QUnit.test( "Test MyClass update", function( assert ) {

  var elem = $('<div />');
  elem.css('top', '10px');
  var c = new MyClass(elem);
  c.update();

  assert.equal( elem.css('top'), '11px', 'top has been updated' );
});
```